# Is there a way to have two different android applications communicate?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make it so that when my app is selected, another app will pop up. Is this possible with intent and service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You have a couple of ways to do this, here is two of them:

1. If you need some kind of long connection and need to move data between the application, you can use two services, one in each side and then communicate with [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) object. Messenger object is use to implement a message-based communication across processes - two different applications, it's easy to use once you get the idea.
2. If you need only to start other app when your app is selected you can start an intent with the intent filter you set in the manifest of the app you want to start. This is what you need if you only need to start the second application, without any connection between them.

If you need to start the calculator application, you can try to do it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What if I do not have access to it's intent filter? How can I get the information? The app I want my app to start is the android built in calculator.

Comment: @DaJaynae Williams Updated my answer.

Comment: "com.android.calculator2" is that just an example package?

Comment: @DaJaynae Williams No this is the real package of the calculator. Try to activate it like this, and see of it is working like you expected.

Comment: How do you know the package is com.android.calculator2?

Comment: @DaJaynae Williams Activate the emulator, then move to the DDMS. There you can see all the applications that you have one your device.

Comment: My DDMS doesn't show anything once the emulator is activated.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is very much possible

to communicate between the apps use [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Intent can be use to launch other apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IPC` (interprocess communication). You can find the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)